# For what values of x ∈ R is the following function decreasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For what values of x ∈ R is the following function decreasing?

$$f(x) = 2x^3 - 9x^2 + 12x + 4$$

my attempts:

first i take at $x= 0$ then $f(0) = 4$
at $x= -1$ the $f(-1) = -2 -9 -12 + 4 =-19$

i thinks  at  $(-\infty,0)$ the function will be decreasing

Is my answer is correct or not. Pliz verified my mistakes

Comment: "I think" is not a justification.

Comment: can u tell me how @ Jack

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is your friend (and everybody else's, too).

Comment: @Ennar I agree, but here the original question was not too hard to read.

Comment: @Peter, yes, but it's not just about one question, it's about informing new members of the standards MSE strives to have.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Find $f'(x)$ which will give you a quadratic equation.

Solve for $$f'(x) \leq 0$$.

Remark about your approach:

Since $f(-1) < f(0)$, it doesn't decreases from $-1$ to $0$. Hence your answer of $(-\infty, 0)$ must be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @ Siong THye GOh

Answer (score 1):

The derivate of $f(x)$ is $$6x^2-18x+12=6(x-1)(x-2)$$

This is positve for $x<1$ and $x>2$ and negative in $(1,2)$, so $f(x)$ is (strictly) increasing for $x\le 1$ and $x\ge 2$. In the interval $[1,2]$, $f(x)$ is (strictly) decreasing.

Hence, the answer is : In the interval $[1,2]$

Comment: Shouldn't that be an open interval?

Comment: No , because $f'(x)=0$ is allowed as well in isolated points.